# RightDoubleClick and context menu

Tags: .net, wpf, mouse, click, double-click

## Related Question (Details)

[Tunneling events and ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464936/tunneling-events-and-contextmenu)

I have a WPF canvas to which I associated a ContextMenu..

This is cool. Now I have to implement some action on Right DoubleClick...

In fact, I never receive on Right mouse ClickCount == 2...

What to do?
**I need to display ContextMenu on simple (right) click, and perform Action2 OnRightDoubleClick..**

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        #region SINGLE CLICK
        stillSingleClick = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(
            new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
                delegate()
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {
                                if (stillSingleClick)
                                {
                                    base.OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp(e);
                                }
                                stillSingleClick = false;
                            }
                    ));
                }
        ));
        thread.Start();
        #endregion SINGLE CLICK
    }
    else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        stillSingleClick = false;
        base.OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Context menus are not displayed as a result of WM_RBUTTONUP, they are displayed as a result of WM_CONTEXTMENU. The reason for this is to allow the keyboard (Shift+F10 or Context Menu Key) to invoke the context menu. There is no way to distinguish WM_CONTEXTMENU being invoked from keyboard or mouse. If you want the behavior specified, you will have to abandon the keyboard functionality. I strongly recommend keeping the 'normal' behavior and instead of right-double-click, use some other mechanism like Ctrl+Left Click.

Comment: @Tergiver: Thanks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464936/tunneling-events-and-contextmenu

Comment: I didn't read the question close enough. I just assumed that the code in the ClickCount="1" statement was some action but now I see that it's basically the same as the answer I provided. My bad.. Deleted answer

Answer (score 1):

`MouseButtonEventArgs.ClickCount` will always be 1 since you are handling an up event not a down event. Both the PreviewUp and Up will always be 1. The click behavior is usually defined as the down event of the respective button.

Comment: @serhio, you simply need to handle the ButtonDown event instead

Comment: @serhio Use PreviewMouseRightButtonDown or MouseRightButtonDown instead of PreviewMouseRightButtonUp

Comment: thanks. See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464936/tunneling-events-and-contextmenu

Comment: the trouble is with ContextMenu

Comment: @serhio You have multiple issues...the issue with your ClickCount is based on subscribing to an incorrect event.

Comment: @Aaron: OK, about ClickCount I understood, the code I provide will not work, because ClickCount always == 1. Multo bene. but the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `MouseDoubleClickEvent`

```
if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
{
     //do something with Mouse Right Double Click
}
```

Comment: the problem is that "MouseDoubleClick" event is not raised on right button if a context menu is active.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount.aspx) example at MSDN:

```
private void OnMouseDownClickCount(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Handle only right clicks
    if (e.RightButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;

    // Checks the number of clicks.
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        // Single Click occurred.
        lblClickCount.Content = "Single Click";
    }
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        // Double Click occurred.
        lblClickCount.Content = "Double Click";
    }
    if (e.ClickCount >= 3)
    {
        // Triple Click occurred.
        lblClickCount.Content = "Triple Click";
    }
}
```

Comment: and what......?  I need to display ContextMenu on simple click, and perform Action2 onDoubleClick..

Comment: what do you mean, and how is linked with your example?

Comment: Just tested and it works so if you down voted you were wrong to do so. I handled MouseDown event instead and used the exact method as posted above and it worked just fine... I added if (e.RightButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return; at the top of the method to avoid handling right click events.

Comment: :) I have no doubt that Microsoft example works, however I down-voted, because is not linked with the problem I have, so is not useful.

Comment: You've lost me... I just added a canvas to my XAML as such <Canvas MouseDown="OnMouseDownClickCount" Width="200" Height="150" Background="Black"></Canvas> and when I perform a single right click on the canvas, code enclosed within if (e.ClickCount == 1) executes and if I perform a double right click the code enclosed within if (e.ClickCount == 2) so this clearly works and it is linked with the problem you have... you're just to fast to down vote people who try to help you withouth waiting for any further clarifications.

Comment: heh. You forgot the contextMenu. See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464936/tunneling-events-and-contextmenu