# Tunneling events and ContextMenu

Tags: .net, wpf, events, canvas

I have the following WPF Control, that should behave like, by e.g. GoogleMaps does(zoom on left double click, unzoom on right double click):

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer">
        <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And some code:

```
void OnScrollViewerPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //this.myCanvas.ContextMenu = null;
    if (e.OriginalSource is Canvas)
    {
        // zoom on left doubleClick
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            ZoomOnMouseOnce();
        } // UNzoom on right doubleClick
        else if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            UnzoomOnMouseOnce();
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that When myCanvas have a ContextMenu the UnZoom method does not work, because DoubleClick event is not catched anymore on ScrollViewer...

Setting `this.myCanvas.ContextMenu = null;` solves the problem, but Is there a way to bypass this?...

Comment: Why don't you ignore the context menu and use a popup to build in the exact functionality you desire?

Comment: @Aaron: this changes nothing. The problem remains the same, context menu or popup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Uploaded small sample project demonstrating the effect.
http://www.mediafire.com/?du2jr18khx8ooy9

I tried a bunch of different approaches for this and the closest thing I found was to offset the HorizontalOffset by 1 for the ContextMenu. This allowed for right-double-click when the ContextMenu was open. It still didn't work when the ContextMenu wasn't open since the ScrollViewer only recieved the first click.

You could work around this by using your timing code for the first right-mouse-click and if another right-mouse-click occurs before the Thread runs out, you simulate another right-mouse-click using SendInput. Although it may not be so pretty, I gets the job done.

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Canvas.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Placement="RelativePoint" HorizontalOffset="1">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem 1"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Canvas.ContextMenu>
```

**Code behind**

```
private bool m_waitingForRightMouseDoubleClick = false;
private void scrollViewer_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
        if (m_waitingForRightMouseDoubleClick == false)
        {
            m_waitingForRightMouseDoubleClick = true;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                        new Action(delegate()
                            {
                                m_waitingForRightMouseDoubleClick = false;
                            }
                            ));
                }));
            thread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            MouseSimulator.ClickRightMouseButton();
        }
    }
}
```

**MouseSimulator.cs**

```
public class MouseSimulator
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct INPUT
    {
        public SendInputEventType type;
        public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MouseInputData mi;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    }
    struct MouseInputData
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [Flags]
    enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
    }
    enum SendInputEventType : int
    {
        InputMouse,
        InputKeyboard,
        InputHardware
    }

    public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting. Till now, finally i used the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492996/invoke-a-contextmenu-to-open

Comment: ah, I see, you "wait" too... the "inconvenient" of method we both use is the perceptible delay between click and menu opening.

Comment: @serhio: With this method, the ContextMenu opens instantly. And from there it'll wait for another click, and if that happends, it actually sends two clicks. Hence, getting us the right-double-click

Comment: @serhio: I uploaded a small sample project. Check it out, I think that's what you're after

Comment: I tested your code. Works almost perfect... surely, we still can see menu appearing on double click. So, you send the second click programatically. Thanks. A good idea.